# select value based on max of other column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a few questions about a table I'm trying to make in Postgres.
The following table is my input:

| id | area | count | function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 20 | living |
| 1 | 200 | 30 | industry |
| 2 | 400 | 10 | living |
| 2 | 400 | 10 | industry |
| 2 | 400 | 20 | education |
| 3 | 150 | 1 | industry |
| 3 | 150 | 1 | education |

I want to group by `id` and get the dominant `function` based on `max` `area`. With summing up the rows for area and count. When area is equal it should be based on max count, when area and count is equal it should be based on prior function (i still have to decide if education is prior to industry or vice versa). So the result should be:

| id | area | count | function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 50 | industry |
| 2 | 1200 | 40 | education |
| 3 | 300 | 2 | industry |

I tried a lot of things and maybe it's easy, but i don't get it. Can someone help to get the right SQL?

Comment: "*based on max area*" - it's unclear to me if you want the "max area" before aggregation or after that

Comment: Before aggregation, because it's all about getting the function

Answer (score 1):

Use a scalar sub-query for "function".

```sql
select t.id, sum(t.area), sum(t.count), 
(
  select "function"
  from the_table
  where id = t.id 
  order by area desc, count desc, "function" desc
  limit 1
)  as "function"
from the_table as t
group by t.id order by t.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e4896/13)

Comment: FYI this is quite slow with a large dataset - `SELECT MAX(...)` takes 20 seconds, but just the subquery on its own using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` takes much longer (I gave up waiting after three minutes).  It seems it has to scan the whole index before discarding all but the first row.

Comment: @Malvineous An index on `id` will fix things.

Comment: Already got an index on that column!  I did some further experimentation though and it looks like it's because I'm using the TimescaleDB extension to Postgres, which doesn't seem to handle this particular case very well, so my apologies, there's nothing wrong with your answer, just don't use it with Timescale :)

Comment: With this query i get the best result in 2 minutes for 6 million records :-) Thnx! Only priority function when area and count are equal is missing.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id, sum(area), sum(count),
       max(function) over (filter where seqnum = 1) as function
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by area desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Another method uses ``distinct on`:

```
select id, sum(area) over (partition by id) as area,
       sum(count) over (partition by id) as count,
       function
from t
order by id, area desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sum as window function:

```
select distinct on (t.id)
id,
sum(area) over (partition by id) as area,
sum(count) over (partition by id) as count,
( select function from tbl_test where tbl_test.id = t.id order by count desc limit 1 ) as function 

from tbl_test t
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the `function` for each group based on `id`:

```
select id, function
from yourtable yt1
left join yourtable yt2
on yt1.id = yt2.id and yt1.area < yt2.area
where yt2.area.id is null;
```

(we ensure that no yt2 exists that would be of the same id but of higher areay)

This would work nicely, but you might have several max areas with different values. To cope with this isue, let's ensure that exactly one is chosen:

```
select id, max(function) as function
from yourtable yt1
left join yourtable yt2
on yt1.id = yt2.id and yt1.area < yt2.area
where yt2.area.id is null
group by id;
```

Now, let's `join` this to our main table;

```
select yourtable.id, sum(yourtable.area), sum(yourtable.count), t.function
from yourtable
join (
    select id, max(function) as function
    from yourtable yt1
    left join yourtable yt2
    on yt1.id = yt2.id and yt1.area < yt2.area
    where yt2.area.id is null
    group by id
) t
on yourtable.id = t.id
group by yourtable.id;
```